# Estimate the Sobolev norm of negative order of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I would like to estimate the Sobolev norm of order $-1$ of the function $f(x)$ which is defined as follows:

Let $\psi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ be a compactly supported smooth function on the real line with the property that
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\psi(x)\; dx = \int^\infty_{-\infty} x\psi(x)\; dx = 0.$$
Let $N>0$ be a positive real number and define $f(x):=\psi(Nx)$. Direct calculation shows that as $N\rightarrow\infty$
$$\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} = O(N^{-\frac{1}{2}}), \quad\quad\quad \|f\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R})} = O(N^{\frac{1}{2}})$$
(here $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ is the usual Sobolev norm). Here are my questions

(1) I suspect $\|f\|_{H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})} = O(N^{-\frac{3}{2}})$, but have no idea how to prove it;

(2) what is the "intuitive" explanation for these growth rates in $N$? Multiplying the variable by a large parameter like $N$ seems a very popular trick, what is this trick good for? Thanks!

Comment: Which definition of the norm in $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ do you use?

Comment: The norm $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as the norm of a continuous linear functional on $H^1(\mathbb{R})$, that is, $$\|f\|_{H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})}:=\sup_{\|\phi\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R})}=1} \left| \int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)\phi(x) \; dx \right|.$$

Comment: Then you can write down that integral, make a substitution $y = N \, x$ and use your knowledge on the behaviour of the $H^1$-norm of re-scaled functions.